# AppCenter and sudo apt "failed to updates"

Tags: release-juno, appcenter

When I try to open AppCenter or do sudo apt-get command. It gives me a error with the following message:

```
E: The package jdk-11.0.4 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Unable to apply corrections for half-installed packages
```

I tried removing jdk-11.0.4 too. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggested, you need to reinstall `jdk-11.0.4`. Please open terminal and execute `sudo apt-get install --reinstall jdk-11.0.4` to reinstall the package.